# UITableViewCell Subclass with XIB Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a `UITableViewCell` subclass `NameInput` that connects to an xib with a custom `init` method.

```
class NameInput: UITableViewCell {

    class func make(label: String, placeholder: String) -> NameInput {

        let input = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("NameInput", owner: nil, options: nil)[0] as NameInput

        input.label.text = label
        input.valueField.placeholder = placeholder
        input.valueField.autocapitalizationType = .Words

        return input
    }

}
```

Is there a way I can initialize this cell in the `viewDidLoad` method and still reuse it? Or do I have to register the class itself with a reuse identifier?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The customary NIB process is:

1. Register your NIB with the reuse identifier. In Swift 3:

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "NameInput", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
   }
   ```

   In Swift 2:

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "NameInput", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
   }
   ```
2. Define your custom cell class:

   ```
   import UIKit

   class NameInput: UITableViewCell {

       @IBOutlet weak var firstNameLabel: UILabel!
       @IBOutlet weak var lastNameLabel: UILabel!

   }
   ```
3. Create a NIB file in Interface Builder (with the same name referenced in step 1):

   - Specify the base class of the tableview cell in the NIB to reference your custom cell class (defined in step 2).
   - Hook up references between the controls in the cell in the NIB to the `@IBOutlet` references in the custom cell class.
4. Your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` would then instantiate the cell and set the labels. In Swift 3:

   ```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! NameInput

       let person = people[indexPath.row]
       cell.firstNameLabel.text = person.firstName
       cell.lastNameLabel.text = person.lastName

       return cell
   }
   ```

   In Swift 2:

   ```
   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NameInput

       let person = people[indexPath.row]
       cell.firstNameLabel.text = person.firstName
       cell.lastNameLabel.text = person.lastName

       return cell
   }
   ```

I wasn't entirely sure from your example what controls you placed on your cell, but the above has two `UILabel` controls. Hook up whatever `@IBOutlet` references make sense for your app.

Comment: Okay basically I have lots of different nibs with different cell subclasses. In the cell for row with index path method how would I go about dealing with the different subclasses? They each have different fields and such.

Comment: Ok, let's say you'll have 50 rows, but that there are, say, three basic different types of cell configurations. So just register those three NIB/XIBs, each with its own reuse identifier. Then `cellForRowAtIndexPath` would, based upon the `row` and `section` of the `NSIndexPath`, dequeue the appropriate cell identifier for the type of cell, and then populate the fields as appropriate.

Comment: FWIW, I actually think working with cell prototypes in storyboards Is a little easier. You don't have to deal with disparate NIB files and everything is right there. But use whatever you're more comfortable with.

Comment: I would agree with you @Rob but the only reason I'm not using prototype cells is that I have to use these same cells in lots of different view controllers, so instead of copying and pasting and having a lot of controller code, I can keep everything in the cell model and have a much cleaner controller while being more efficient.

Comment: As of Xcode 6.3.2., I have to use `as!` instead of `as` in the dequeue.

Comment: Yes, as of Swift 1.2, you use `as!`. Obviously this answer pre-dates that, but I've updated it for you.

Comment: Thanks for the super clear explanation. I had a prototype cell that I needed in another, different ViewController. I was able to just create a NIB file, delete what's in it, then copy the cell from the storyboard, paste it into the NIB, and was good to go. Deleted it from storyboard, followed the above steps to register it, and all worked like a charm. Thanks. Keep it DRY - don't repeat yourself.

Comment: As @jamespick said, this makes the most sense when you're re-using cells in different view controllers.

Comment: I follow your step but after hooking up the references with the XIB it crashed and shows "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name." Can you please help me to figure out this problem?

Comment: @TapasPal - That error is telling you that you have some outlet called `name` in the NIB which does not exist in the base class. Either you didn't specify the base class correctly or you hooked up an outlet to `name` but later removed or renamed that property.

Comment: @Rob thanks for you quick reply. I am not very sure what was the problem. I just restart my computer and the same code work.

Answer (score 3):

You don't initialize cells in `viewDidLoad`. You should register the XIB, not the class, with your table view.  You should set up the label and text field in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` (possibly by calling an instance method on `NameInput`).

Comment: Thanks haha Ive been staring at your answer for a while but now I understand thanks