# segmented control with tableView, disable UIImage Cell in the second and the third segment

Tags: swift, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I want disable UIImage Cell in a specific segment control, because all the images in 0 segment show up in the second segment and third segment

2)second question : how to change the size of my UIImage in table view to be a circle ? 
Please find below my code for my segment control

```js
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        switch(mySegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
        {
        case 0 :
                myCell.textLabel?.text = example1[indexPath.row] as? String
                myCell.imageView?.image = images[indexPath.row]
            break
        case 1 :
            myCell.textLabel?.text = example2[indexPath.row] as? String
            break
        case 2 :
            myCell.textLabel?.text = example3[indexPath.row] as? String
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    return myCell
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The image will be there when your cell is dequeued if it was set while showing the first case so for the other cases you have to set it to nil.

```
    switch(mySegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
    {
    case 0 :
        myCell.textLabel?.text = example1[indexPath.row] as? String
        myCell.imageView?.image = images[indexPath.row]
    case 1 :
        myCell.textLabel?.text = example2[indexPath.row] as? String
        myCell.imageView?.image = nil
    case 2 :
        myCell.textLabel?.text = example3[indexPath.row] as? String
        myCell.imageView?.image = nil
    default:
        break
    }
```

2) try this after dequeueing the cell

```
myCell.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius = myCell.imageView?.frame.width / 2
```

Comment: @moryia  Awesome thanks ! Can you answer to my second question is up there and I will accept your answer ! thanks again

Comment: I did something like that but still I have the same problem myCell.imageView?.frame = CGRect(x: myCell.imageView!.frame.origin.x, y: myCell.imageView!.frame.origin.y, width: 20,height: 20)

Comment: There might be a way to do this with the standard cells but at this point it's just better practice to create a custom cell with a xib that you build according to your image size preferences. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28489720/uitableviewcell-subclass-with-xib-swift