# Populate the tableView with JSON data

Tags: ios, json, swift

Here i am trying to load the table view with JSON data but data is not showing up. I don't know where the problem is i think i am not getting data into array properly.Tried a lot but not getting what i am doing wrong.New to iOS.

Below is my **JSON data:**

> {"total_images_count":266,"datetime_value":"2016-07-15
>   19:28:37","total_count_response":"","image_path":"http://www.expert.com/test/images/","task":[{"image_name":"file1","image_path":"1461468362622.jpg"},{"image_name":"file2","image_path":"1461468362622.jpg"},

```
 class ViewController:    UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

var arrDict :NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

     jsonParsingFromURL()

}

func jsonParsingFromURL () {
     let url = NSURL(string: "http://clipbyte.com/ontest/cron/webapi.php?task=webapi.getAllClips")

     let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)

     NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {(response, data, error) in
        self.startParsing(data!)
    }
}

func startParsing(data :NSData)
{
    let dict: NSDictionary!=(try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)) as! NSDictionary
    for var i = 0 ; i < (dict.valueForKey("task") as! NSArray).count ; i++
    {
        arrDict.addObject((dict.valueForKey("task") as! NSArray) .objectAtIndex(i))
    }

    NSLog("array is ", arrDict)
}


func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
{
    return 1
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return arrDict.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

    let cell : UITableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")

    let strTitle : NSString=arrDict[indexPath.row] .valueForKey("clip_name") as! NSString

    cell.textLabel!.text=strTitle as String
    cell.imageView?.image = arrDict[indexPath.row].valueForKey("clip_image_path") as? UIImage
    return cell

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

if i use the below class for custom cell it gives me error at init function below IBOutlet

TableViewCell class

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell
 {
@IBOutlet weak var lblTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lbDetails: UILabel!

init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String) {
super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
// Initialization code
}
 override func awakeFromNib() {
 super.awakeFromNib()

// Initialization code
}

 override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
 super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
 // Configure the view for the selected state
}
}
```

Comment: Reload your tableView on main thread once the data it added into the data source array.

Comment: You should use tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath instead. If you assign arrDict.count to an variable and then on the next line return that variable, then you can set a breakpoint on that return statement and see the value, what is the value?

Comment: Where is reloaddata method

Comment: Suggestions: stop abusing the force-unwrapping operator, you're begging for crashes. Also, Swift lets you write code that looks like Objective-C but you shouldn't do it, use Swift native types and methods instead.

Comment: I have printed the array using NSLog but it is not printing anything...it is giving only array is

Comment: ... and stop abusing `valueForKey:`

Comment: Any other way i can show image without using nib file please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a function to run a closure on main thread:

```
typealias Closure = () -> Void
func runOnMain(closure: Closure) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        () -> Void in
        closure()
    })
}
```

Then in your method `startParsing`

Finish by reloading tableView:

```
func startParsing(data :NSData)
{
    let dict: NSDictionary!=(try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)) as! NSDictionary
    for var i = 0 ; i < (dict.valueForKey("task") as! NSArray).count ; i++
    {
        arrDict.addObject((dict.valueForKey("task") as! NSArray) .objectAtIndex(i))
    }

    NSLog("array is ", arrDict)
    runOnMain {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Edit:
A tip is to create a Macros.swift file without any class and put the runOnMain method and typealias in that file. That way that method is accessible from anywhere in your project.

Also you should really create Models from your JSON. I suggest you take a look at my [open source project](https://github.com/Sajjon/SwiftIntro) which fetches data using Alamofire and parses the JSON into models.

Comment: thanks for the answer it worked can you tell me why this was happening @Sajjon

Comment: and also i have to show the image using imageView also so what should i do @sajjon

Comment: You are calling the method "startParsing" inside the closure of an async request, but the GUI runs on the main thread (aka "the GUI thread"). So you have to be on the main thread and update the GUI, by telling the TableView to reload itself

Comment: Regarding displaying images I like "Kingfisher", it has an nice extension on ImageView you can use, check it out here: https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher#uiimageview-and-nsimageview-category

Comment: @virat do you wanna accept my answer if it helped you? :)

Comment: i have to show the image also in using image view..i have update the json data see the JSON..how can i do that...can you please help me with that.

Comment: @virat in the JSON it looks like the "clip_image_path" is a relative URL? not an absolut url to some image on the internetz? So do you have the image downloaded on disc already?

Comment: ya i will surely accept the answer but do i have to use the custom cell and use a separate class for it to show the image.

Comment: I would always recommend creating a custom cell (Xib with corresponding Swift file), but it is not needed to should the image. All UITableViewCells have an imageView already, [see documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/imageView)

Comment: but what if i have to show image in complete cell and show its name below in label@sajjon

Comment: Yeah I recommend a custom cell if you dont want the default layout that you get from using the default UITableViewCell. Just google "Swift custom tableviewcell" and you will get lots of help with this.

Comment: You can also get inspiration from [my open source project](https://github.com/Sajjon/SwiftIntro) I dont have TableViewCells but custom UICollectionViewCells (which use the same pattern).. that I populate with JSON data a create models for. Maybe it can be an inspiration to you! :)

Comment: i am using above class to show the text on custom labels but it gives me error at init method which is below label outlet

Comment: Once again, please check my project for inspiration... You have not registered you custom class on the TableView..? You in viewDidLoad for in ViewController with the TableView you have to call tableView.register either a nib or a cell. Then you have to dequeue the cell using the same identifier as you used when regestring. Then return that cell. You should set the labels in your cell in [willDisplayCell](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:)

Comment: Take a look at this [DatasourceAndDelegate class](https://github.com/Sajjon/SwiftIntro/blob/master/SwiftIntro/DataSourceAndDelegates/MemoryDataSourceAndDelegate.swift) used for UICollectionView, but it is the exact same pattern for UITableViews

Comment: Thanks a lot Sajjon that you are helping me but please can you explain me this in code ... You in viewDidLoad for in ViewController with the TableView you have to call tableView.register either a nib or a cell it will be grateful if you will do that coz i don't have that much idea where to register and do the stuff .

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28490468/1311272

Comment: ok in that so i have to put the register for nib method in view controllers viewDidLoad method ? wand what is that nib name for ?

Comment: The nib name is the name of the Xib file you have created for your custom cell

Comment: Can't i add imageView and label in tableView's cell and change class of the cell on storyboard with our CustomClass that i will create and what is Xib file is it the other name of our viewController

Comment: You should create your own xib and use register on the tableview in viewdidload :). Good luck and please accept my answer if I was of any help! :)

Comment: one last question see my code for imageView tell me what am i doing wrong it's not showing the image    cell.imageView?.image = arrDict[indexPath.row].valueForKey("clip_image_path") as? UIImage   @Sajjon

Comment: It is not an image! You are trying to set and image on an imageview with a variable that is a string! Using Kingfisher you can set the image on the imageView using a URL to an image on the internet. Kingfisher will download the image for you. But as I said, the value of clip_image_path seams to be a relative url... so that would work....

Comment: but i am still confused how should i create a Xib file

Comment: Google is your friend my friend! :) "swift create custom tableview cell xib"