# TableView CellReuse

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have problems with my custom cell file in tableview. I managed to get it done using the out comment line shown below, but the performance was really bad when it had 10+ cells. 
UsingdequeueReusableCell leads to this error:

*'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier DiveNewsShort - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'*

which is strange, because I do register the nib in viewDidLoad(). I hope you can help me, I am getting frustrated by this.

```
class ProfilTableView: UITableViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "DiveNewsShort", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "DiveNewsShort")

    tableView.register(DiveNewsShort.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "DiveNewsShort")
  }

public override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

  // let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("DiveNewsShort", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! DiveNewsShort
  // This one works as expected

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DiveNewsShort", for: indexPath) as! DiveNewsShort
  // This one does not

return cell }
```

[image: StoryBoard Picture]

---

Update:

I managed to get rid of the error by adding the register function in the cellForRowAt function, but I don't think that this is a efficient way actually. It should work within the vieDidLoad shouldn't it?

```
public override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "DiveNewsShort", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "DiveNewsShort")
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DiveNewsShort", for: indexPath) as! DiveNewsShort

return cell }
```

Comment: Why are you making two calls to `tableView.register` for the same identifier?

Comment: Set the base class in the NIB and don't register the class, just register NIB. Or use cell prototype in storyboard and you don't need NIB at all, nor any manual registering of anything. But if you're reusing the NIB in multiple tables, then registering NIB is fine approach (but don't obviously have any cell prototype).

Comment: have you set the cell identifier in the storyboard ?

Comment: I added a picture of the storyboard. Regarding the register calls, I just added a few examples from other projects to test, but nothing worked. As you can see in the picture, the xib file is called DiveNewsShort just as the TableViewCell class.

Comment: Your registering of the NIB should be in `viewDidLoad`, not `cellForRowAt`. Register only once for each identifier.

Comment: Thats what I am trying to do, but registering in viewDidLoad is not working

Comment: OK. It's just that you shared a `cellForRowAt` and you show us an attempt to register there, which is incorrect.

Comment: We're getting to a point of diminishing returns here, methinks. You might want to create a blank project and reproduce your problem with a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and upload that someplace where we can take a look. Both [reinier's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43478716/1271826) and [that other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28490468/1271826) I shared with you show how to do it. There must be something simple you're doing wrong, but it's not apparent until you share a MCVE with us.

Comment: @Rob I created an [MCVE Version](https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/couchsports/DiversMCVE.zip) It works if the registering is done at cellForRowAt, otherwise it crashes. Furthermore I found a bug: Every 8. cell is duplicate, changing values also changes every 8. cell value too. I hope this is just is caused by the wrong implementation.

Comment: The bug there is a deeper problem, completely unrelated to the code snippet in your question. You have a confusing (and completely unnecessary combination of a table view controller within view controller). When all of this strange code was removed, it works precisely just like Max, Reinier, and I outlined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways to register cells for reuse/dequeuing:

1. You are programmatically creating the cells, in which case you register the class in `viewDidLoad`.
2. You are using a NIB, in which case you register the NIB in `viewDidLoad`.
3. You are using storyboard cell prototypes, in which case you don't have to register anything. The storyboard does all of this for you.

Since you are using NIBs, you should remove the registering of the class and only register the NIB. And you should do this in `viewDidLoad`. This process is outlined in https://stackoverflow.com/a/28490468/1271826 as well as in [Reinier's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43478716/1271826).

Looking at [your MCVE](https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/couchsports/DiversMCVE.zip), your problem was a result of a more fundamental mistake, where you had a `UIViewController` trying to use another view controller, which was a `UITableViewController`, to manage the table. But `UITableViewController` has its own `UITableView` and won't use the one that you have an `@IBOutlet` for, so you were registering the NIB for a table view you weren't seeing. There were a ton of other issues here (e.g. if you really want a view controller within a view controller, you have to do view controller containment calls, etc.), but the simplest solution was to excise this separate `UITableViewController` from the project and when this was fixed, it works precisely as we described. See https://github.com/robertmryan/Divers for a working version of your MCVE.

You also didn't hook up the outlets for the other two controls in your cell (the switch and slider). Thus, if you changed either of those two controls and then scrolled, the cells are reused and you see the changed UIKit control that was done for some other cell, but was subsequently reused. To fix that, your custom `UITableViewCell` subclass should have outlets for *all* controls, and `cellForRowAt` must set values for all of these outlets. You also need some mechanism for the cell to inform the view controller when the switch and slider have changed and update the model accordingly, so when `cellForRowAt` was later called for that row, it would know the state of that `CellData` to set the control appropriately. A common solution for this is to use the protocol-delegate pattern. See the above GitHub repo, which illustrates this pattern, too.

Comment: As an aside, there's nothing in your MCVE that suggests that you have to use NIB. I might suggest using a storyboard cell prototype instead. It keeps the entire UI defined in the storyboard.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much Rob! I suspected that using separate view controllers may be an error source but I am not familiar with tableviews at the moment and I thought separating would be a good idea. Turns out its not or I am not smart enough for it at the moment :-) The nib file is totally bs atm, there will be more complex content and it will be used in different tableviews later on. I just put some things in it for debugging, thats why it was not connected to the code. Again thank you so much for your patience and effort!

Answer (score 3):

You don't need this line:

```
tableView.register(DiveNewsShort.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "DiveNewsShort")
```

You already have registered the nib file one line before.

Comment: @Zorro02 - Did you set the base class in your NIB? I assume you do not have any cell prototype? Is the error the same as before? Edit your question, supplying additional details.

Comment: @Rob I don't have any prototype cell. How do I set the base class in the NIB? Do you mean the Custom Class?

Comment: That's good you don't have cell prototype if you're using NIB. Yes, I wanted to make sure the custom class was set (not to be confused with the identifier). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/28490468/1271826 for the list of steps for NIB for table view cell.

Comment: @Zorro02 check my answer hope helps you

Answer (score 0):

I have build this protocol for help me in this process

```
protocol CBNibInstanceableCellProtocol {
    static func getCellXib() -> UINib?

    static func getReuseIdentifier() ->String
}
```

and in your class you have to implement those methods like here

```
//example implementation
extension CBUsersAttendanceEmptyCell : CBNibInstanceableCellProtocol
{
    static func getCellXib() -> UINib?
    {
        if Bundle.main.path(forResource: "CBUsersAttendanceEmptyCell", ofType: "nib") != nil
        {
            return UINib(nibName: "CBUsersAttendanceEmptyCell", bundle: nil)
        }
        return nil
    }

    static func getReuseIdentifier() ->String
    {
        return "CBUsersAttendanceEmptyCell"
    }
}
```

then in your `viewDidLoad` you must do something like this

```
//example code
self.collectionView.register(CBUsersAttendanceAvatarCell.getCellXib(), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CBUsersAttendanceAvatarCell.getReuseIdentifier())
self.collectionView.register(CBUsersAttendanceCountCell.getCellXib(), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CBUsersAttendanceCountCell.getReuseIdentifier())
self.collectionView.register(CBUsersAttendanceEmptyCell.getCellXib(), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CBUsersAttendanceEmptyCell.getReuseIdentifier())
```

in your cellForRow

```
if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CBUsersAttendanceCountCell.getReuseIdentifier(), for: indexPath) as? CBUsersAttendanceCountCell
        {
            return cell
        }
```

You must have defined the class for you view in your xib, this is very important check this pictures

[image]

[image]

Hope this helps